# Access private AWS API gateway Endpoint from NGINX Controller on EKS

Tags: aws-api-gateway, integration, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I want to be able to access a Private API Gateway Endpoint, hosting my APIs from EKS Cluster.
I am using Service (Type:Externalname) - (apigw-service) to point to my Private API Gateway Endpoint https://xrx5x3nap5.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.

This EKS Cluster is running Nginx Ingress Controller. FOllowing is the configuration of my Ingress and Service to achieve above.

```
---
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: ingress-api
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  spec:
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - api.example.com #replaced actual domain due to privacy
      secretName: tls-cert #This contains the Key/Certificate for this Domain
    rules:
      - host : "api.example.com"
        http:
          paths:
            - path: /(.*)$
              pathType: Prefix
              backend:
                service:
                  name: apigw-service
                  port:
                    number: 443
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apigw-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: xrx5x3nap5.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com #this is Private API Gateway URL and has assocated VPC Endpoint
```

Please suggest if I will be able to achieve above. i.e call API Gateway Endpoint from Ingress Resource in EKS. If so, kindly guide further

```
$curl apigw-service     #Running it in POD within EKS Cluster
```

This gives the IPs of the VPC Endpoint associated with API Gateway

```
$curl https://xrx5x3nap5.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Test/ --verbose     #Running it in POD within EKS Cluster
```

This gives the results

```
$ kubectl describe ing ingress-api

Name:             ingress-api
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          ad320b322e8114f27b42328c7b243343-xxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
TLS:
  tls-cert terminates api.example.com
Rules:
  Host                             Path  Backends
  ----                             ----  --------
  api.example.com
                                   /(.*)$   apigw-service:443 (<error: endpoints "apigw-service" not found>)
Annotations:                       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                                   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
                                   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
                                   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: true
                                   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                 From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    45m (x4 over 109m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Additionally the curl command to the domain name gives the following output

```
    $ curl https://api.example.com/Test --verbose --cert client.crt --key client.key -k


  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying [64:ff9b::34d7:6bfa]:443...
*   Trying 52.31.79.62:443...
* Connected to api.example.com (52.31.79.62) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [19 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [1268 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [520 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [52 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [52 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=api.example.com
*  start date: Apr 21 14:08:52 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 20 14:08:52 2024 GMT
*  issuer: C=AU; ST=Some-State; O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
} [5 bytes data]
* using HTTP/2
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0* h2h3 [:method: GET]
* h2h3 [:path: /Test]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: api.example.com]
* h2h3 [user-agent: curl/7.88.1]
* h2h3 [accept: */*]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x27809f214b0)
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /Test HTTP/2
> Host: api.example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.88.1
> accept: */*
>
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/2 403
< date: Wed, 26 Apr 2023 10:01:35 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 23
< x-amzn-requestid: 6836ad23-cc0e-48de-ae79-ab3041e3e322
< x-amzn-errortype: ForbiddenException
< x-amz-apigw-id: D-tz8GrmDoEFq1A=
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
<
{ [23 bytes data]
100    23  100    23    0     0     18      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    18{"message":"Forbidden"}
* Connection #0 to host api.example.com left intact
```